# how to rectify this type of error SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
create procedure usbinsertbookDatainto
   @Bookno Numeric,
   @studentno Numeric,
   @currentnoofcopiesavaillable varchar(300),
   @Issuedate datetime,
   @Duedate  datetime
AS
 BEGIN
  Insert into tbluseraccount
        (
          Bookno,
          studentno,
          currentnoofcopiesavaillable,
          Issuedate,
          Duedate
         )
         values
          (
           @Bookno,
           @studentno,
           @currentnoofcopiesavillable,
           @Issuedate,
           @Duedate
            )          
END
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   usbinsertbookDatainto, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'AS'.
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 2,
>   Procedure usbinsertbookDatainto, Line
>   22
>   Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@currentnoofcopiesavillable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the first occurrence of "(" and
remove the last "," from your list of vars

```
create procedure usbinsertbookDatainto

 @Bookno Numeric,
 @studentno Numeric,
 @currentnoofcopiesavaillable varchar(300),
 @Issuedate datetime,
 @Duedate  datetime

AS
 BEGIN
  Insert into tbluseraccount
        (
          Bookno,
          studentno,
          currentnoofcopiesavaillable,
          Issuedate,
          Duedate
         )
         values
          (
           @Bookno,
           @studentno,
           @currentnoofcopiesavillable,
           @Issuedate,
           @Duedate
            )          
END
```

Comment: or replace the last "," with ")" SQL Servers supports parameter lists both with and without brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo: in your parameter list for the stored proc you have:

```
create procedure usbinsertbookDatainto
   ... 
   @currentnoofcopiesavaillable varchar(300),
```

and in the code you use:

```
     values(.....
@currentnoofcopiesavillable,
```

So to make it clearer:

```
Defined:  @currentnoofcopiesavaillable 
Used:     @currentnoofcopiesavillable
```

Make sure to type the same variable name as you've used in the declaration!